# Remove a layer with z-index position

Tags: jquery, popup, z-index

I have a popup with a blank layer under popup.
The number of z-index of blank layer is always one number less than popup.
When user clicks on close button in the popup, I should remove popup layer and blank layer.
I can remove popup layer easily but how can I remove blank layer ?

This is my jQuery code for removing popup :

```
        var curZIndex = $(this).closest('.popup').css('z-index');
        $(this).closest('.popup').remove();
```

UPDATE:

```
<div style="width: 1263px; height: 756px; opacity: 0.8; background-color: black; position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 103;"></div>

<div style="width: 1263px; height: 756px; opacity: 0.8; background-color: black; position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 100;"></div>

<div style="width: 1263px; height: 756px; opacity: 0.8; background-color: black; position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 95;"></div>

 ... ANOTHER TAGS ...

<div class="popup" style="left: 144.5px; top: 100px; z-index: 104; width: 957px;">
  <div class="popup_bc_top">
    <div class="popup_bc_tl"></div>
    <div class="popup_bc_tm"></div>
    <div class="popup_bc_tr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup_bc_middle">
    <div class="popup_bc_ml">
      <div class="popup_bc_mr">
        <div class="popup_bc_cnt" style="height: 590px;">
          <div class="inner_popup" style="z-index: 102; width: 951px;">
            <div class="inner_popup_bc_top">
              <div class="inner_popup_bc_tl"></div>
              <div class="inner_popup_bc_tm"><a class="closeIcon" href="#closePanel">X</a></div>
              <div class="inner_popup_bc_tr"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_popup_bc_middle">
              <div class="inner_popup_bc_ml">
                <div class="inner_popup_bc_mr">
                  <div class="inner_popup_bc_cnt" style="height: 550px;">
                    CONTENT
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_popup_bc_bottom">
              <div class="inner_popup_bc_bl"></div>
              <div class="inner_popup_bc_bm"></div>
              <div class="inner_popup_bc_br"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup_bc_bottom">
    <div class="popup_bc_bl"></div>
    <div class="popup_bc_bm"></div>
    <div class="popup_bc_br"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE 2:

I have more than one blank layer, so I cannot use `$('#hideLayer').remove();`
but the z-Index of just one layer is one number less than my popup layer.

Comment: you should post the markup related to the blank and popup layer

Comment: @F.Calderan I added HTML codes

Comment: *I can remove blank layer easily but how I can remove blank layer?*. Is that a typo?

Comment: @VisioN yes, sorry, I update my post

Comment: You shouldn't need multiple blank layers, just calculate the height and set it appropriately. Anyways, a simple solution to work with what you have would be to add a class to each one and call hide() on that selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is then:

```
$('#hideLayer').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the blank layer using its id:

```
$('#hideLayer').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

**After the line:**

```
$(this).closest('.popup').remove();
```

**Call the same procedure to the background layer:**

```
$("#hideLayer").remove();
```

---

**Take note** that you are removing those elements from the document! They will not be available later on!

If you need them to be available for reutilization, you should use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)